# How to combine jquery response with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

```
success: function (response) {
$.each(response, function(k, student) {
<td>'+student.test_status+'</td>
```

In the above `<td>` i am getting **value as 1 or 2** 
i want to show that if the value is 1 show message if 2 show another message like that i can do this with php i want to combine with jquery how can i do that..?

```
    <td>
    <?php if('+student.test_status+' == 1) { ?>
    <span style="color:green"><?php echo "GD completed"; ?></span>
    <?php } else if('+student.test_status+' == 2) { ?>
    <span style="color:green"><?php echo "PI Completed"; ?></span>
    <?php } else { ?><span style="color:red"><?php echo "Not Started"; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    </td>
```

I want solution something like this.

Comment: for starters read up on how php array and object syntax works. It is not the same as javascript and one can only guess where the extra `+` sign idea came from. You are expected to at least do basic research before asking questions here. This isn't a code writing or tutorial service

Comment: Do you suggest any documentation link related to my question..? @charlietfl

Comment: sure...the php manual, and the web is full of tutorials

Answer (score 3):

try this make sure js is in the same file of the php follow the below codesnippt

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
            $('<tr>').html(
                $('td').text(item.rank),
                $('td').text(item.content),
                $('td').text(item.UID)
            ).appendTo('#records_table');

        });
```

you need to append to the records_table in the HTML markup

```
<div id="records_table"></div>
```